# XACML policy location

Tags: xacml

Is it possible to store XACML policies anywhere in the file system (e.g. c:\users\simo\projects\project1\policies)?
if the answer is yes how to configure the jbossxacml-config.xml ?

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
<ns:jbosspdp xmlns:ns="urn:jboss:xacml:2.0">
  <ns:Policies>
    <ns:Policy>
       <ns:Location> c:\users\simo\projects\project1\policies\policy1.xml</ns:Location>
    </ns:Policy>
  </ns:Policies>
```

The exception is the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Null Inputstream for c:\users\simo\projects\project1\policies\policy1.xml
org.jboss.security.xacml.core.JBossPDP.<init>(JBossPDP.java:171)
```

Thanks,
Simo

Comment: Simo, you probably want to provide a better description. What XACML engine are you using? It seems you are using JBoss's PicketBox. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am using JBoss's PicketBox as the PDP engine. BTW I found the answer to my question, I should have used a Java URI format for the policy file location, i.e.,

```
<ns:Location>file:///c:/Users/simo/project1/policies/policy1.xml</ns:Location>
```

Thanks